# How to order a Parent Child Hierarchy in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

**This is my data:**

```
$scope.data = [{
        id: 1,
        group: 'Parent Comment 1',
        pid: 0
    }, {
        id: 2,
        group: 'Parent Comment 2',
        pid: 0
    }, {
        id: 3,
        group: 'Child 1 P1',
        pid: 1
    }, {
        id: 4,
        group: 'Child 1 P2',
        pid: 2
    }, {
        id: 5,
        group: 'Parent Comment 3',
        pid: 0
    }];
```

I want output as below:

```
ParentComment 1
Child 1 P1
Parent Comment 2
Child 1 P2
Parent Comment 3
```

I tried using orderBy but was unable to get desired output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To output such a (two-level) tree, you just provide an orderBy predicate expression as an array:

```
['pid || id', 'id']
```

That means following:

- the first ordering criteria will be either `parentId` or `id`, if the former is 0. With this trick child and parents will be grouped in the output...
- ... but, as you 1) still need to place the parents above the children, and 2) order children themselves, there should be a second criteria - `id` alone.

In other words, your `ng-repeat` might look as following:

```
<tr ng-repeat="record in data | orderBy:['pid || id', 'id']">
   <td>{{record.group}}</td>
</tr>
```

[**Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/3chVlxEfBwDFmUuwRmr0?p=preview).

---

If you need to process more complex hierarchies, it's probably better to reorganize your data so that each parent comment contains all the children comments. Still, it's possible to implement a predicate for the existing structure too:

```
$scope.predicate = function(el) {
  var res = [];
  while (el.pid) {
    res.unshift(el.id);
    el = $scope.data[el.pid - 1];
  }
  res.unshift(el.id);
  return res;
};

...
<tr ng-repeat="record in data | orderBy:predicate">...
```

... but there's a catch: in this code, I assume that `id` of an element is linearly mapped to its position in the source array. Otherwise you'll have to either look for it at *each* step, or implement an index; both ways are cumbersome.

Comment: And if instead of a 0 indicating no parent there was null? How would you do it then?

Comment: And the difference is? `null` is as falsy as `0` is. Do not confuse it with `'null'` (a string); the latter can be checked against directly, but the whole approach smells bad for me.